# Translate jQuery to Express function

Tags: express, momentjs, pug

I've been trying to show a clock on my website for a few hours, I'm using express js and pug, the function I have shows me the time, however it doesn't cycle to do it every second, in jquery it works perfectly for me.

Jade, Pug, Express JS, Node JS

Pug + jQuery

```
script.
      function update(){
        $('#clock').html(moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY H:mm:ss a'));
      }
      setInterval(update, 1000)
```

Express JS
app.js

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { mensaje: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')});
});
```

Index.pug

```
.col-md-6
  span#clock.clock 
.col-md-6
  p= mensaje
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *in jquery it works perfectly for me*?

Comment: In jQuery It’s Works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I understood what you said : you want to make a clock using express + pug and expect the same behaviour as what you had with pug + jquery.

They don't work the same way.

With express, you're doing a webserver, which is listening to request and give a response. It only send a new response (updated data) when you make a request.  Jquery is on the client side so you can easily refresh the view with new data.

So If you want to keep using express you should either consider use [websocket](https://socket.io/) so that express will be able to send continuous data to your view. Or, make the request every second (which is not the best way in terms of perf and might not suit with render method).

Usually the best way to display something very versatile (like a clock) is doing it client-sidely so your jquery approach was the best in your case (in my opinion).

Comment: What can I do for jQuery to be as fast as the Express server, with jQuery, it takes too long to load?

Comment: did you try to use minified version of jquery so that the import of the library isn't that heavy for the browser ?